# I want to check if textbox value is equal to my specific value

Tags: javascript, html

I try to check with my button if my textbox value is equal to the specific value,which i have defined.I cannot find the solution.

Here is my js:

```
<script>  
    function Checked(){
        var text = document.getElementsByName( "Phone" );
        if(text == "1234567890") {
            alert("Congratulation");
        }
        else{
            alert("Wrong Phone");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="ISO-8859-7">
            <title>Main Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Password:
        <input type="text" name="Phone" pattern="1234567890"">
        <i>Press here:</i>
        <button onclick="Checked()">Check me
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't check the rest yet but there is a syntax error in your HTML code: `pattern="1234567890""` - there is a `"` too much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.value` to get the text inside the text box and compare that:

`var text = document.getElementsByName("Phone")[0].value;`

Comment: Thanks you very much.Your answer is correct and quick.

Answer (score 0):

The `document.getElementsByName` function returns a collection of elements. You have to choose one of them (in your case it's probably the first one) and then you have to access its `value` property:

```
var text = document.getElementsByName("Phone")[0].value;
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.Your answer is correct and quick.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `document.getElementsByName()` will return an array, so comparing `text` to a string will automatically fail. If there's only one element that you want to look up, give it an ID and look it up via `document.getElementById`. Furthermore, you need to retrieve the `value` of that element, because this returns an object (again, not a string):

JS:

```
var text = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
```

HTML:

```
<input id="phoneNumber" type="text" name="Phone" pattern="1234567890">
```

Of course, it's often wise to tread on the side of caution and check for nullity:

```
var text = document.getElementById("phoneNumber");
if(text) {
    var phoneNumber = text.value;
} else {
    alert("No phone number.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much.I will do it.